# во view:source вместо кириллицы вижу коды символов

Tags: asp.net, кодировка, asp.net-core

данные достаются из базы (MS SQL Server 2017)
Collation у базы: Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
проходят через ASP.NET Core
и вставляются в разметку таким видом:

```
@Model.Text
```

после чего я вижу такое во view-source

```
&#x41F;&#x43E;&#x446;&#x44B;&#x43A;
```

если использовать @Html.Raw(Model.Text) то текст отображается нормально, но это не решение проблемы.

upd: проблема точно не в базе
во View пишу @(new string ("привет")) и вижу опять эти коды символов

Answer (score 0):

Решено

```
services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options => 
{
      options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
});
```

https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/315